# Why is my saleservice not being created after creating a sale?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following method in my controller with nodejs and expressjs

```
const Sale = require('../models/Sale.model');
const Service = require('../models/Service.model');
const SaleService = require('../models/SaleService.model');
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');
const asyncHandler = require('../middleware/async');

//@route   POST /api/v1/sales
//@desc    Create Sale
//@access  Private

exports.createSale = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { services, customer_id, employee_id } = req.body;

    const sale = await Sale.create({ employee_id, customer_id });

    const saleServices = await Promise.all(services.map(async (serviceData) => {
        const { id } = serviceData;
        const service = await Service.findByPk(id, { attributes: ['id'] });
        if (!service) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`Service with id: ${id} not found`, 404));
        }

        return await SaleService.create({ 
            sale_id: sale.id, 
            service_id: id, 
        });
    }));

    res.status(201).json({ sale, saleServices });
});
```

I have a many to many relationship within `services` and `sales`. So in my method I create a sale with a `employee_id` and a `customer_id` and for each service I want to create a `saleservice` with the `sale_id` that I´ve just created and a `service_id`.

For some reason the sale is being created as expected, but the saleservices are never being created at all.

Non error is shown in the console either.

This is my associations.js:

```
const User = require('./User.model');
const Employee = require('./Employee.model');
const Sale = require('./Sale.model');
const Service = require('./Service.model');

Sale.belongsToMany(Service, { through: 'Sale_Service', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
Service.belongsToMany(Sale, { through: 'Sale_Service', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
User.hasOne(Employee, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'Employee', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
Employee.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'User', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });


module.exports = { User, Employee, Sale, Service };
```

This is my Service.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Service = sequelize.define('Service', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    service_code: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true    
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
 
    },
    service_date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(20,2),
        allowNull: false,
    },

});

module.exports = Service;
```

Sale.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const Sale = sequelize.define('Sale', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    employee_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'employees',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    customer_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'customers',
            key: 'id'
        },
        required: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    
});

module.exports = Sale;
```

SaleService.model.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/db');

const SaleService = sequelize.define('SaleService', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    sale_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'sales', 
            key: 'id'
        },
    },
    service_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'services',
            key: 'id'
        },
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'SaleService', 
    timestamps: false, 
});

module.exports = SaleService;
```

Why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you try to turn on the SQL logging and see what's going on there?